# What type of korban may be brought jointly by more than one person?

Tags: korban, kodshim

The Pesach offering is brought on behalf of a group, who then eat it.  What other types of sacrifices may be brought jointly, by 2 or more people?

Comment: I assume you mean to exclude all sorts of public communal offerings. Since it seems you are getting answers which surprisingly don't assume that, you should probably [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why surprising? You yourself on other occasions refuse to make assumptions interpreting the meaning of a question. Why did you make assumptions here? The question only asks what types of sacrifices may be brought jointly, NOT "what individual sacrifices not proscribed for daily or holiday offering may be brought jointly."

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky The Tamid, Musafim, and Par He'lem Davar are not brought jointly. They are brought by the community. The Kohein Gadol's Par is owned only by him (at least originally). I make no special assumptions other than the literal meaning of his words.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36654/discussion-between-isaac-kotlicky-and-double-aa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Olah (even of a bird) or a Shelamim can be brought jointly ([Rambam Maaseh Korbanot 3:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1017015/jewish/Maaseh-Hakorbanot-Chapter-3.htm)), but not Menachot ([ibid. 14:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1017026/jewish/Maaseh-Hakorbanot-Chapter-14.htm)).

Answer (score 3):

- In the event that a Beis Din issues an incorrect ruling, resulting in the majority of the nation sinning, a communal offering is brought. [In some cases, they bring individual offerings for each Tribe.](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/horayos/insites/ho-dt-005.htm) This is known as a Par He'elem Davar (a cow [brought due] to a hidden matter) and is discussed in Maseches Horayos.
- It may be possible for two or more individuals to bring the same Korban Todah as shutafim (such as if it was in response to a joint miracle). These are [classified as shelamim](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1017021/jewish/Maaseh-Hakorbanot-Chapter-9.htm) according to the Rambam, and thus [may be brought jointly.](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1017015/jewish/Maaseh-Hakorbanot-Chapter-3.htm)
- As DoubleAA states, an Olah may also be brought jointly, but a mincha may not.
- The 70 Korbanos of the Sukkos are brought on behalf of the nations of the world, as Chazal state. (Sukkah 55b)
- The [Korbanos of Yom Kippur](http://www.shemayisrael.co.il/dafyomi2/yoma/chart15.htm) are brought on behalf of 1) the family of the Kohen Gadol 2) the Kohanim in general and 3) the whole nation, made clear in the associated declarations of the Kohen Gadol. ([Yoma](http://kodesh.snunit.k12.il/b/h/h25.htm) 3:8, 4:2 and 6:2)
- the Korban Tamid (and all other communal korbanos) are [purchased out of communal funds](http://www.torah.org/learning/beyond-pshat/5763/kisisa.html), being brought on behalf of the entire nation.

Comment: The other Kohanim don't contribute to the Par Kohein Gadol IIRC. Everything else here is just Korbanei Tzibbur which seems to not be what he is referring to.

Comment: Do you have any sources for these claims? Please [edit] them in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36651/discussion-between-isaac-kotlicky-and-double-aa).